# How to create a loop in Animation Nodes (now that it has been updated)

Tags: node-editor, animation-nodes

At [2:32](https://youtu.be/hCzwcyieHto?t=2m32s) in Jacques Lucke's video on how to use loops in his epic Animation Nodes addon, he uses two nodes that are now revised.

Supposedly the actions that `Loop Call` and `Loop` did in older versions can now be done with `Loop Input` and `Invoke Subprogram`.  This is all fine and dandy, however I can't figure out how to get the `Replicate Object` node (now called `Object Instancer`) to do the same thing.

How do I get the same effect he does in that example using the updated version of Animation Nodes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> > *Object* > *Instancer*

You can also use the Search Tool:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>, then type "instancer"

[image: Object Instancer]

[image: Loop]

Answer (score 4):

In this particular case you can make use of some tools that come with the AN addon that help you to create the loop faster:

[image]

Search Box: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>

Pie Menu: <kbd>W</kbd> (when the Object Instancer node is active)